# Who has revealed more about a secret password?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, cryptography

Today, Bob, a colleague of mine, accidentally revealed that his password contains `a`. Alice laughed, but then also inadvertently said her password does *not* contain any `a`.

Who has given away more about his/her password? In other words, whose password is now easier to guess?

EDIT: I have purposedly *not* provided information about the length of any password, or even maximum length. One can assume the *maximum* length to be unbounded. I.e. let the variable `m` representing the maximum password length in any formulae, tend towards infiny.

EDIT2: I picked "Alice" and "Bob" as a homage/reference to the homework problems in my undergraduate course's books. But this really happened. A colleague of mine has a defective `a` in his keyboard.

EDIT3: Here's my stab at the question that I arrived at with my colleagues over lunch yesterday:

Let's write the formulae for the number of possible passwords given an alphabet of integer size $\alpha$ and a maximum password length of $m$

$\sum_{n=1}^m \alpha^n$

This I arrived at by summing "$\alpha$ passwords of length 1" + "$\alpha^2$ passwords of length 2" + ... + "$\alpha^m$ passwords of length $m$".

Now, Alice has revealed she doesn't have an `a` anywhere in her password. She has reduced the alphabet size to the attacker by 1. So the total number of passwords for her is:

$N_{Alice}=\sum_{n=1}^m (\alpha-1)^n$

Bob's total number of possible passwords has also decreased:

$N_{Bob}=\sum_{n=1}^m \alpha^n -\sum_{n=1}^m (\alpha-1)^n$

In other words, $N_B$ has decreased exactly the same amount as the number of possible passwords for Alice, which *have* the letter `a`.

Now, if $m$ is [the totally unrealistic value of] 1, Alice has clearly given away her password completely, while Bob still has $\alpha - 1$ total passwords.

But, as an *intuition* as $m$ increases towards infinity, I think $N_{Alice} << N_{Bob}$, so I think it is Alice who is now more likely to have his password brute forced!!

My calculus is a bit shaky :-) so I do not know yet if it is true that $N_{Alice} << N_{Bob}$ as $m$ tends towards infinity. If this question is reopened, perhaps someone can help me.

EDIT4: Trial-and-error in a simple program seems to confirm my intuition. For an alphabet size of 26, if the maximum password length is 17, Bob has given away more. If it is 18, he wins (Alice has given away more).

Comment: Assuming that Alice and Bob are not real friends of yours, this smells like homework in Introduction to Cryptography course or something similar. Given that this is indeed homework, what have you tried?

Comment: It depends on the alphabet and on the average length of the passwords. For example, in an alphabet with only two characters $a,b$, the password of Alice must have the form $b\dots b$, so it is easy to guess.

Comment: Given a password of length $n$, which may contain any one of $m$ unique symbols any number of times: The probability of guessing Bob's password is $1-\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^n$. The probability of guessing Alices's password is $\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^n$. So this answer basically depends on the values of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @barakmanos: it sure sounds like homework, but amazingly isnt' This happened a few hours ago at a meeting. But Bob and Alice are an homage to homework, yes.

Comment: Jus a quick note, I don't believe you can assume a "maximum password length of infinity", because a "maximum" is something obtained, and if something is unbounded, then the maximum just does not exist. I think you want to say the password has unbounded length.

Comment: That's not exactly what I said, I said the maximum length, say the variable `m`, is infinite. I meant that an answer should be obtained by making `m` go towards infinity. But OK, I'll edit. If the question  is reopened I would like to answer it. Or should I add that as an edit?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume both have a password length of $N$, and an alphabet size of $s$.

Then the first has a possible $s^N - (s-1)^N$ many passwords: all passwords except those that are all from the alphabet without an a.

The other has $(s-1)^N$ many passwords.

Now compare...

Comment: I didn't make that assumption in my question. Can you try again without it?

Comment: It will always depend on the alphabet size and length. Make realistic assumptions (like $N=8$ and $s=62$) and compare the numbers. It will be pretty clear I think.

Comment: are you saying that without those "realistic assumptions" there are no statement that can be made regarding, for example, the change in the mean time to brute-forcing each of those passwords before *and* after the information was provided inadvertently by Alice and Bob? I disagree.

Comment: Incidently, the only truly "realistic assumption" is that you _don't_ know the length of anyone's password, any more than you know the passphrase. You just know it is finite.

Comment: Intuitively, this will mean that if the passwords are long enough that they "ought to have an $a$" (more characters than there are in the alphabet), Alice has removed more possibilities.  If they are shorter than the number of characters in the alphabet, Bob has removed more possibilities, because the password "should not have an $a$".

Comment: Ah, Ross, that's beginning to sound like a useful reasoning, in line with mine. I'll try to answer the question myself in an edit, just have to figure out this mathjax thing again.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depend on two things:

1. First the length of the password
2. The size of the alphabet used for the password

Assume that the passwords have length 1 Bob did give away his password but Alice didn't.

However if you have only 2 possible letters (say a and b) then it is Alice that gave away her password (a sequence of b's).

Comment: except for the length of the password ;)